# How to fix BAD_REQUEST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have  a problem, when I use postman it always be 400 even the header contain application/json and the body contain full information need

[image: Controller]

[image: postman header contain application/json already]

[image: payload]

I want to fix it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, you have defined the function as @PutMapping("/{email}") and in your url you are writing localhost:8080/update/{your_email} which seems to be incorrect. As there is empty string defined for the url (only the param is mentioned) so the url should just be localhost:8080/{your_email} instead of localhost:8080/update/{your_email}.

Comment: it have @RequestMapping("/update") in the above, the screen shot is not full

Comment: ok then giving the method a url before the path variable email should work. Like this, @PutMapping("/profile/{email}").